# Literal Flatten NULL object or Array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to flatten an JSON object contained in a column of my table, which has an optional field.

```
-- row 1
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "key3": [1, 2, 3]
    }
    
}
-- row 2
{
    "key1": "value1x"
}
```

From the above example lets assume the table is from table "X" and column "A"
My query to select:

```
SELECT
   x.id, -- another column in table X
   key3
FROM X AS x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(A.key2.key3) AS key3
```

The resulting table:

```
id  |  key3
___________
 1  |   1
 1  |   2
 1  |   3
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
id  |  key3
___________
 1  |   1
 1  |   2
 1  |   3
 2  |   NULL
```

Any ideas how to do this?
One idea is to `UNION` for all the NULL object is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you want to do what you wanting to do aboce by the way ? It does not make sense to me what and why you are trying to print resulting table above.

Comment: I am guessing you meant "why would I want to do the example above?" Well the JSON object is originally from a NoSQL database that populated by several micro services.
under some concurrency circumstances multiple "profiles" for a single customer. "key3" represents the historical "ids" of these customers after consolidation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get non-existing values [OUTER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html#arguments) option could be applie:

> OUTER
>
> If TRUE, **exactly one row is generated for zero-row expansions** (with NULL in the KEY, INDEX, and VALUE columns).

```
SELECT
   x.id, -- another column in table X
   key3
FROM X AS x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUTY => A.key2.key3,OUTER => TRUE) AS key3
```

Comment: yes. right I was going to post the answer after find it out as well.